# How long are UK Crown Court Hearing Recordings kept?

Tags: united-kingdom, recording, court-records, crown-court

As the title suggests, I am wondering how long UK Crown Court Hearing Recordings and transcripts are kept because in order for court transcripts to be requested, the recordings need to be still available.

The government's guidance on how to [Apply for a transcript of a court or tribunal hearing](https://www.gov.uk/apply-transcript-court-tribunal-hearing) does not stipulate this information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seven years.

See the paragraph 13 of the [Crown Court Records Retention and Disposition Schedule](https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/911194/crown-court-rrds.docx):

> 13 Recordings of trials -- Keep for **7 years** and then destroy

For awareness, and completeness, the list of retention schedules for other courts and tribunals may be found [here](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/record-retention-and-disposition-schedules).

Comment: Presumably the [Word document](https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/911194/crown-court-rrds.docx)

Comment: Thanks to @Henry for the link